# Unable to authorize to couchdb using $.couch.login

Tags: javascript, jquery, couchdb

in my CouchDB setup i have the following configuration

- CORS in configuration is enabled (it worked before i locked down the database)
- a basic admin with name `admin` and password `admin` exists

localsite is `http://localhost/mysite` and couchdb is located in `http://localhost:5984/`

*i have avoided to use any server-side scripting and just serve the static files, the rest is handled in client-side, so if it's possible, do not write your entire answer based on server-side `PHP` or `node.js`.*

Tried to login with `$.couch.login` it returns

`{"ok":true,"name":null,"roles":["_admin","admin"]}`

the i try to request `$.couch.session` and instead of a populated json it justs returns

`{"ok":true,"userCtx":{"name":null,"roles":[]},"info":{"authentication_db":"_users","authentication_handlers":["oauth","cookie","default"]}}`

when i tried with a REST tool , the result was

`{"ok":true,"userCtx":{"name":"admin","roles":["_admin","admin"]},"info":{"authentication_db":"_users","authentication_handlers":["oauth","cookie","default"],"authenticated":"cookie"}}`

when worked with the REST tool, it allowed me to continue , with adding documents, deleting , and so on.

What exactly am i missing here?

Comment: is your `admin` user a server admin or database admin? as far as i remember you need database admin to get what you expect.

Comment: `admin` user is server & database admin & a member of that database.
does it make a difference if `admin` has that many roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the following code allowed for cookie in headers.

`$.ajaxSetup({`
`crossDomain:true`
`,xhrFields:{ withCredentials:true}});`